# Access 2016 Accde Running On 2013 Runtime failed once we split to FE and BE

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

We do development of our application with office 365 pro plus.
We have a stand-alone Access 2016 application that works fine with access runtime 2013 installed on our client machine.
To do that we did simply refer to the mso.dll for office 15.

We did try to split the database but when we run on client which has a different office 365 of us. As the stand alone app, The application start, display the ms access security notice than simply fail without any error trapping message we did put on the code.

Any idea how to fix this without upgrade our client to office pro plus

Comment: If you haven't solved this question yet you might want to delete this one and then re-post it using the `ms-access` tag as well so that it is actually seen.

Comment: Did you enable macroses (active content) for new file/office installation? The best way is to add a folder with application to the list of trusted locations in Access Trust Center.

Comment: Why don't you use the Access 2016 Runtime?

Comment: it's a plan but we do not have control on the PC deployment. They still have access 2010 application running on 2013 runtime.

Comment: For this apps only, we use 2 types of file server on network,Unix for development and Novel for production. It looks that the network security on Novel network (production) is the issue for some users. I will confirm that in the next days.

Comment: Issue is solved. it's was a Novel network security issue and also some machine were not configured as our machine used for development. Question should I delete that post ?